# Https webhook with client certificate (mutual TLS)

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

Good day!
I've got grafana v9.3.6 on RHEL.
Trying to configure alert webhook on https-endpoint, but getting such error

```
Failed to send test alert.: Post "https://*address*/api/v1/connection-pool/alpha/state": remote error: tls: certificate required
```

The client certificates are located at etc/pki/tls/certs, I have a symlink at etc/ssl/certs:

```
   518 0 lrwxrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jan 31 2023 ./certs -> ../pki/tls/certs
```

How do you defeat the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Grafana doesn't support client certificates (mutual TLS) for alert webhook.